# How to add and remove fields with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a large form with the fields being drawn out dynamically, based on a schema. (i'm looping through a JSON schema to write my fields).

Some of my fields are nested, so the naming convention follows a dot-notation;

```
ParentField.ChildField.Name
```

This will automatically nest the data as it's input;

```
ParentField {
  ChildField {
    Name: "Value of field"
  }
}
```

redux-form provides a FieldArray that allows you to `push()` fields on demand, but this changes the format of the data to include arrays of info - **not** what i want!

So i need to be able to register and unregister fields on demand (button click for example)

The documents point to actionCreators but i can't figure out how to implement them.

Comment: Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026301/redux-form-with-self-creating-inputs

Comment: This is not helpful @Neeraj. This talks about FieldArrays - specifically something i don't want

Answer (score 10):

You can use `registerField` and `unregisterField` action creators.

Just import them in your file

```
import { registerField, unregisterField } from 'redux-form';
```

and then in your code dispatch the action simply:

```
this.props.dispatch(registerField(yourFormName, yourFieldName, fieldType));
```

(`fieldType` being either string 'Field' or 'FieldArray') and

```
this.props.dispatch(unregisterField(yourFormName, yourFieldName));
```