# how to append list of strings to the text area in react, redux-form as a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

[image]

i am planning to develop a form as shown in the mockup , when i click on add admin button it should take the value from text field and append to the text area as list and when i submit the form i should be able to send the text area values as an array to the backend.

i have tried this [click here to see the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl1xqqk074) go to simpleform.js

i am using redux form for this and i have to create same thing in multiple places in the same form , can some one suggest how to do it in best way where i can reuse the same code or component in multiple places.

Comment: Is there a reason to using text area? Should the emails be modifiable after they have been put into the list? I would say modify the text area to just be a div/span combo that displays the results, right?

Comment: @ageoff not necessarily text are but i want some thing where i can scroll. is it a good idea to use table ? and challenging is to save it in redux-form state

Comment: where have you been for last few years? https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/ - scrollable list with actions (remove) in rows can be suitable? try formik, not redux-form

Comment: @xadm i have a huge form ,been already using redux-form , thats the reason i am looking for a solution with redux-form

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40092627/6124657

Comment: @xadm  i have already seen that example in redux-form documentation but i wasn't able to complete my requirement

Comment: whitch one? having list, converting to text and back?

Comment: on page loading , it should show one button and input text field , then when i click on add button it should update the form state in the redux state , probably from the state i can read and display in my custom table or list

Answer (score 0):

Your sandbox ... after small fix

```
addEmail = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
```

seems to adding elements to list (2 lists?) but custom textarea gets array as value ...

if you need it done properly for `redux-form` (I feel pain after working with formik) you should use `<FieldArray />` with custom renderer.

I minimally modified standard Field Arrays Example to make working POC with textarea, scrollable text div, scrollable item list:

```
const renderHobbies = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => {
  const val = Array.of(fields.getAll()).join('\n '); // docs claim getAll returns an array ;)
  console.log(val);
  return (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push("aaa")}>Add Hobby</button>
    </li>
    <textarea value={val}/> 
    <div style={{ overflowY: "auto", overflowWrap: "break-word", height:50, width:100}}>{val}</div>

    <div style={{ overflowY: "auto", height: 200 }}>
      {fields.map((hobby, index) => (
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0m81vzjx3w

Adding value from input shouldn't be a problem - f.e. standard setState, fields.push(this.state...)

UX is really bad (Autodesk?) if you know that there should be [one/multiline multi select component MUI](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/) with search, adding custom values ...

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but my requirement is totally different , again saying same thing on page load it should show only one button and a text field and what ever i enter in text box on button click it should add to list , and should be able to sit those list values with in the redux-form state

Comment: THIS IS what you need (button, input add youself, array stored in redux-form, deeper, in outer array but IT IS DONE redux-form way), if you can't see similiarity or can't extract this parts then go, try another, new path, fight with it ... yourself